# Are asp.net mvc partial views really slow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, partial-views

i use partian views for render rows of my table. Render of one partion view take about 80ms. 
So when i have 100 records in my table it takes 8 seconds just to render a table! My partional view is enough simple. Is it asp.net mvc problem (i.e. mvc renders partional really slow) or i must to search problem source in another way?

( i used asp.net mvc mini profiler to get time of rendering partial views)

Comment: Partial views aren't slow.  Can you show your code that's rendering the table?

Comment: Where specifically is the bottleneck?  The mere fact that it's a partial view shouldn't be causing a performance problem.  Does the problem go away if you render it all in one view instead of partials?  (That is, if you take the markup from the partial view and just put it inside a loop in the main view)?

Comment: @David Yep, it is not partial view problem. When i changed code of my partial view to simple text it begin work much faster